# Gaussian processes with covariance $K(s,t)=G(s)G(t)$, what properties do they satisfy?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_t)$ be a Gaussian process with covariance $K(s,t)=G(s)G(t)$ for a given $G$. What does that mean for the process $(X_t)$ ? For example if the covariance has the form $K(s,t)=G(\min(s,t))$ where $G$ is non decreasing and positive means that $(X_t)$ has independent increments.

Do you have an example of such an $(X_t)$ ? Maybe based on Brownian motion ? What properties should it satisfy ? It feels like the covariance is so rigid that $(X_t)$ should be very specific.

EDIT:  $X_t=G(t)X$ where $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ would yield such a process. I am wondering if this is the only way to get such a covariance. This would confirm the "triviality" of those processes.